# Update Fails in AppCenter

Tags: updates

Unable to update (from AppCenter) "xdg-desktop-portal desktop integration portal for Flatpak and Snap Version: 1.7.2-flatpak1~bionic"

The words contained within quotes above comprise the description listed under Operating System Updates.

As a workaround that prevents the update from appearing in AppCenter, I disabled these deb and deb-src repositories: ppa.launchpad.net/alexlarsson/flatpak/ubuntu/

Comment: > I disabled these deb and deb-src repositories: ppa.launchpad.net/alexlarsson/flatpak/ubuntu/ How? I’m having the same issue with the constantly-reappearing update and would like to do the same

Comment: Brandon, I have Synaptic Package Manager installed. Using it, disabling specific repositories is easy: Go to Settings > Repositories from within the package manager's user interface.

Comment: see also: https://github.com/flatpak/xdg-desktop-portal/issues/547

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexlarsson/flatpak/ubuntu` ppa.

You might've added it from various guides around the internet when flatpak was released, that's how I got it. It's no longer needed as, since 5.1, elementary supports flatpak out of the box.

Source: https://github.com/elementary/os-patches/issues/145